# What is the number of nodes in input layer of the following artificial neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This is for MNIST datset

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=((28,28))))
```

Doesnt flatten create the input layer to have 728 nodes, so that each each pixel value is inputted in the neurons/nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, flatten take a multi-dimensional tensor of shape and return a vector tensor so the output shape will be the product of each dimension. In your example the output will be of size 28 * 28 = 784.

Comment: From the above code, does this denote two layers or single layer? ie from the above code is the input layer having 784 neurons? or flatten code creates a hidden layer next to input layer with 784 neurons

Comment: I am trying to write a report, and I am still new to this. So I would be so grateful if you can help me out

Comment: Flatten is only a single layer I believe, it is equivalent to a reshape. So you would have your input neurons and and a flatten layer turning your 28*28 input tensor into 784 neurons.

Comment: Thanks bud :) really appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome :). Good luck for your report.